# Selecting (and filtering) MySql rows with distant relation count

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-database

I have 3 entities:

A street
which has many Houses
which have many Windows

In MySql it would look like this:

```
Street          House                      Window
-------------   -------------------------  ------------------------
| id | name |   | id | street_id | name |  | id | house_id | type |
-------------   -------------------------  ------------------------
| 1  | SA   |   | 1  | 1         | HA   |  | 1  | 1        | WA   |
-------------   -------------------------  ------------------------
| 2  | SB   |   | 2  | 3         | HB   |  | 2  | 1        | WB   |
-------------   -------------------------  ------------------------
| 3  | SC   |   | 3  | 1         | HC   |  | 3  | 1        | WC   |
-------------   -------------------------  ------------------------
```

I need to be able to write some queries that in plain English would be:

- Fetch each street with a count of how many windows there are on it
- Fetch all the streets having no windows

I can't figure out how to do this, the problem is that Windows are owned by Streets via Houses.

I've tried something like this:

```
SELECT street.*, COUNT(*) AS window_count FROM street
LEFT JOIN house ON street.id = house.street_id
LEFT JOIN window ON house.id = window.house_id
GROUP BY street.id
```

This seems to produce the result I want but this is extremely slow (over 2 mins). I need the LEFT joins because I want to return all Streets, even if they have no Houses or Windows.

Any ideas on the best way to do this? The amount of difficulty I am having makes me suspicious of my database structure, perhaps I need to store this data differently?

Comment: It's likely that the only thing you're missing is indexes.  If you index `house.street_id` and `window.house_id` I bet these queries will go nice and quickly.  P.S.  Use `COUNT(window.id)` to correctly account for houses/streets with no windows.

Answer (score 0):

This code could run faster, because it is grouped before crossing

```
SELECT 
    street.*, 
    CASE WHEN wc IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE wc END AS window_count
FROM street
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT street.id, SUM(WH) AS wc
    FROM house 
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT house.id, COUNT(*) AS WH 
        FROM window 
        GROUP BY house.id
    ) AS W 
    ON house.id = W.house_id
    GROUP BY street.id
) AS H
ON street.id = H.street_id
```